# Device not found message when run xcode app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Device not found message when run xcode app
Xcode version : 7.3
os version : EI Capitanenter image description here

[image]//i.stack.imgur.com/VbYIr.png

Comment: can you try unplug and plug in device again?

Comment: unplug device and plug again wait till phone completes files processing then select your phone in devices ,Cmnd+R

Answer (score 2):

Just plug out your phone and plug in again and wait until it process the symbol files and start displaying in the simulator list.

Also clean your code once.

Comment: also try uninstalling the app from the device.

Answer (score 0):

this issue generally occurs just because you update xcode or made some changes in application folder.
To fix this Quit xcode and restart again or Restart your Mac

Another solution is

Clean your Project and try to re run the project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clean Your Code. Then Build And Run.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your xcode and open again that project and run it. 
Its work for me.

May be Its helpful to you